# Design advice, do I need multiple stores, or a plugin to keep retail/wholesale separate?

Tags: extensions, multistore, customer-group

Client wants to keep retail customers/guests from purchasing (or even seeing) wholesale items.  Also wants wholesale users to not be able to buy retail items, so there should never be a case where retail items and wholesale items are in the same order.  Wholesale items will exist on a page that requires login, and they have unique skus from the retail items.

Would best practice be:

1) Create a wholesale category, and a plugin that removes non-wholesale items form the cart when a wholesale group member logs in (and hide the retail order button for wholesale users)?

2) Create a wholesale store in a subdirectory, and limit only the wholesale group to have access.  Would this prevent retail/wholesale items from being added to the same cart?

3) ...?

1 feels wrong, but I started on 2 and I'm realizing I have no idea how to share the menu and such between the views, or even setup the product page.  While 1 seems like a hack, at least it's a hack I think I can do.  Any and all advice is very welcome and much appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Magento. This feature has already been implemented. It allows you to hide and show products and categories based I on the customer group. https://github.com/Vinai/groupscatalog2

Comment: Thank you for the welcome and the link.  Do you know if that extension removes items from the cart on login.  So if a guest adds a retail item, then logs in as a user in the wholesale group, would the retail item get pulled out of their cart?  I don't see mention of that in the documentation.

Comment: Hmm, good question. I don't know, but..If it's not configurable in backend, I may just code that in during the weekend and submit a feature request. The more I think about it, the more I'm convinced it should be configurable per store.